# Using RelativeLayout inside RadioGroup make RadioButtons not exclusive

Tags: android, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I'm trying to make a RadioGroup with two radio buttons in the horizontal and vertical center. But also I want that they stay aligned by they radio since they had different text length. I used this code, but they are not mutually exclusive :

```
      <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center|center_vertical">

                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/rbtn_gps_to"
                    android:text="to"
                    android:checked="true"
                    />


                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/rbtn_gps_from"
                    android:text="from"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/rbtn_gps_to"
                    />


            </RelativeLayout>


        </RadioGroup>
```

It works, both are aligned as I wish , but the problem is that when I check one and then I check the other , the first one stay also checked, so they are not exclusive. When I remove the Relative Layout the radiobuttons are exclusive. Is any way to create the layout that I want and the radiobuttons remain exclusive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previous answers contains some issue. The dots to selected are not in one column, they are not aligned. This is solution which looks the same like your.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width=" wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rbtn_gps_to"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="to"/>
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/rbtn_gps_from"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="from"/>
    </RadioGroup>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If I use it the buttons are not displayed. If I change in layout width wrap content by match_parent they are displayed on the left, they are not in the center horizontal

Comment: so let's try my new solution

Comment: RadioButton extends LinearLayout, and its behaviour is the same. If you want to do some special you have to add additional layout

Comment: Did you try my new solution?

Answer (score 0):

Hi use the following below:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radio_group_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RadioButton

        android:id="@+id/rbtn_gps_from"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="from" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbtn_gps_to"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="to" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: It puts the RadioButtons  in the top. I need them in the center horizontal and vertical. Also they are not aligned by their radio

Comment: Now they are int the center, but not aligned by their radio :(

Comment: Try above sowi was using old one :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do the layout you need by setting xml property of radioGroup to vertical.

```
 <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/rbtn_gps_to"
                android:text="to"
                android:checked="true"
                />


            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/rbtn_gps_from"
                android:text="from"

                />

    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: the problem with this is that they are in the center but not aligned by their radio